# error X3671: loop termination conditions in varying flow control cannot depend on data read from a UAV

Tags: directx11, deferred-rendering, compute-shader

I have a problem with converting my pixel shader to compute shader.
The error is in this piece of code:

```
 [numthreads(32,32,1)]
 void CS_PostDeferredReflex( uint3 nGid : SV_GroupID, 
     uint3 nDTid : SV_DispatchThreadID, uint3 nGTid : SV_GroupThreadID )
 {
   if (any(nDTid.xy >= float2(SM_SCREENX, SM_SCREENY))) return;
   uint Output = UAVDiffuse0[nDTid.xy];
   float4 ColorOut = float4(Output&0x000000FF, (Output&0x0000FF00)>>8,
                       (Output&0x00FF0000)>>16, (Output&0xFF000000)>>24)*INV255;
   float D = txDepth1.Load(uint3(nDTid.xy,0), 0);D=(D==1)0:D;
   if (ColorOut.a*D == 0) return;
```

Which gives the following:

`error X3671: loop termination conditions in varying flow control cannot depend on data read from a UAV`

Here the UAV `UAVDiffuse0` is a `R32UINT` that is unpacked as `RGBA ColorOut`.

If the alpha value is zero (or the Depth not [0<D<1]) I don't need to go further. The compiler is unhappy with the last line where the exit is based on the UAV read. I don't understand why we have this limitation.

Comment: [I notice that `for` loops have the option of an `[allow_uav_condition]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-for), but I don't see a similar attribute that can be applied to `if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is effectively to use [allow_uav_condition] but in the right place

what does not work is to place the condition before the if statement even if it is where I need it

```
 [allow_uav_condition]
 if (ColorOut.a*D == 0) return;
```

in the code I have a loop so what works is to place the condition before the loop, even if in the loop I have no test against the UAV, just write to it.

```
 ...code
 if (ColorOut.a*D == 0) return;
 ...code
 [allow_uav_condition]
 for ()
 {
   ....code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I set the A channel of my UAV into another texture which solve the problem but it is annoying as this needs an extra 8 bit resource and my UAV alpha channel is now useless.